# Maximum tags for a question on any SE site

Tags: discussion, support, tags

Is the maximum tags for all SE sites (and those in the future) 5?

Comment: It would seem like this is the case.

Comment: So it's not something that can be changed per site

Comment: @rchern: As this would have a direct relationship to the SE engine itself, I can with confidence say that it is unlikely this will be changed on a per-site basis.

Comment: This question belongs on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com); it applies to the whole SE architecture in general.

Comment: @BrockAdams it was relevant as I was consuming the API. Also this is 9 years ago..

Comment: Jeesh, @Jonathan. Next you'll say that [*Meta Stack Exchange* wasn't even a thing when](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/04/17/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/) you asked this question.  ;)  It doesn't change the fact that MSE is the best place for this kind of core-architecture question now.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment the number of tags allowed on a question is 5. Both client side and server side this limit is now<sup>1</sup> enforced at the time of posting.

There is no direct limitation to allow 6 or even 7 tags. As a matter of fact, this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1059156) shows 1038 questions at the time of posting that have 6 tags. The revision for [one occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1119886/4) reveals what caused that 6th tag being added, a CM and their fancy scripts, bypassing all business rules.

However, allowing more tags might run into the length limitation of the field `tags` in the `Posts` table. That single field hold the concatenated tagnames, enclosed in `<` and `>`. It allows for 250 characters at the moment. As the tagname length has been increased to 35 characters, the technical limit is barely seven tags if those tags all have 35 characters.

---

<sub>1. in the early days of SO this check was broken, as evidenced by [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/173/2)</sub>

Comment: I don't blame Shog9, I blame VBA.

Comment: Looks like [Stack Overflow is the only site where this has occurred](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1059222/list-of-questions-with-more-than-5-tags-for-all-se-sites).

Comment: @BrockAdams yeah, I recall Shog9 mentioned once that a question had 7 tags. Can't find the source.

Comment: [found it](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/696/2) and [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/163/2) and [example 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/173/2) but these all seem early days mishaps / cc @BrockAdams (and the query for posthistory: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1059223)

Comment: Sweet!  And there is a slight chance that one might be able to hack [the rollback mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/173/revisions) to get > 5 tags. But I'll leave that for Jeremy to try to exploit...